# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I already tried all previous answers and solution.

I am trying to use this value, which gave me encoding related error.

```
ar = [u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anne_Hathaway', u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jodie_Bain', u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wendy_Divine', u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jos\xe9_El\xedas_Moreno', u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Baaba_Maal']
```

So I tried,

```
d = [x.decode('utf-8') for x in ar]
```

which gives:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried out

```
 d = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in ar]
```

which removes error but changes the original content

original value was `u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jos\xe9_El\xedas_Moreno'` which converted to `'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jos\xc3\xa9_El\xc3\xadas_Moreno'` while using `encode`

what is correct way to deal with this scenario?

**Edit**

Error comes when I feed these links in

```
req = urllib2.Request()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: what do you want to do with the data? ASCII encoding does not support those characters. That's why we have encodings such as uff-8. I'd highly advise on skipping ASCII if you plan on using this application out in the wild.

Comment: If you already have unicode strings, then you don't want to `decode()` them into unicode strings. :-)  It's likely you want to interact with something that requires a non-unicode strings, which means putting it in an acceptable encoding via `encode()`.  These days, that usually UTF-8, but it really depends on what you're trying to do and the service you're interacting with.

Comment: @SiddharthShukla: I store this links into my solr database, and later match it with `links` given from users. While dealing with user input link value, I get this issue. I dont want to change the way link looks

Comment: @niper In that case you would just want to go with the most common encoding: utf8. You could also just store it the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

The second version of your string is the correct utf-8 representation of your original unicode string.  If you want to have a meaningful comparison, you have to use the same representation for both the stored string and the user input string. The sane thing to do here is to *always* use Unicode string internally (in your code), and make sure both your user inputs and stored strings are correctly *decoded* to unicode from their respective encodings at your system's boundaries (storage subsystem and user inputs subsystem).

Also you seem to be a bit confused about unicode and encodings, so reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942594/41316) and [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

`Unicode strings` in python are `"raw" unicode`, so make sure to `.encode()` and `.decode()` them as appropriate. Using `utf8` encoding is considered a best practice among multiple dev groups all over the world.
To encode use the `quote` function from the `urllib2` library:

```
from urllib2 import quote
escaped_string = quote(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

To decode, use `unquote`:

```
from urllib2 import unquote
src = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jos\xc3\xa9_El\xc3\xadas_Moreno"
unicode_string = unquote(src).decode('utf-8')
```

Also, if you're more interested in Unicode and UTF-8 work, check out [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and

Answer (score 0):

In your Unicode list, `u'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jos\xe9_El\xedas_Moreno'` is an ASCII safe way to represent a Unicode string. When encoded in a form that supports the full Western European character set, such as UTF-8, it's: `http://dbpedia.org/resource/José_Elías_Moreno`

Your `.encode("UTF-8")` is correct and would have looked ok in a UTF-8 editor or browser. What you saw after the encode was an ASCII safe representation of UTF-8.

For example, your trouble chars were é and í.

```
é = 00E9 Unicode = C3A9 UTF-8
í = 00ED Unicode = C3AD UTF-8
```

In short, your `.encode()` method is correct and should be used for writing to files or to a browser.